# Mis-information in private beta invite email FAQ section

Tags: bug, email, private-beta, commitment

In the FAQ (the formatting of which could do with being bold and maybe a `:` after the word) has this text:

> Q: Who can access the site during the private beta?
>   A: Only the 207 people who committed to it.

This isn't quite true - people can invite others. Could this be changed on the email to reflect the correct information, perhaps to something like this:

> Q: Who can access the site during the private beta?
>   A: The 207 people who committed to it, and any people they invite to participate via email.

---

**Update:** Shadow Wizard has informed me that anyone can access the private beta via clicking the Area 51 link. This means the whole section should be removed.

Comment: Anyone can access private beta by simply clicking the link to it in the Area51 proposal. This whole thing needs to be removed. (the private beta thing only protects it from being indexed or accessed by mistake by outside visitors)

Comment: Oh! Didn't know that at all - I'll edit to update that.